# Reusing styles in SASS/SCSS without merging selectors

Tags: css, extend, sass

If I have a style definition in SCSS that looks like this:

```
#someid {
    ...
    .message {
        ...
        &.error {
            // overrides of .message class
        }
    }
}
```

So I display some kind of messages in my UI which can be normal message (have `.message` class) or errors (have both `.message.error` classes).

Now I have a different element that displays similar info in normal an erroneous way, that's why I would like to replicate error settings.

**How do I use @extend directive** without putting styles in a separate class and then extending/using it in both `.error` styles or using a mixin for the same purpose? I would just like to reuse the same style definition.

The problem is that it combines all kinds of class inheritance when I do an `@extend`.

```
#otherid {
    ...
    .notification {
        ...
        &.error {
            // should use the other ".error" style
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the compiled results has this style definition which is a mix and match of merged selectors:

```
#someid .message.error,
#someid #otherid .message.notification.error,
#otherid #someid .message.notification.error
```

While I would rather have just these two:

```
#someid .message.error,
#otherid .notification.error
```

### Can this at all be done?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Could you use a @mixin?

```
// Define here
@mixin generic-error {
  // Error styling
}

// Replace original
.notification {
  &.error {
    @include generic-error;
  }
}
```

Comment: Well that's the same/similar to having a separate class and extend it in both of the other classes... but it's also one of the possible solutions. That's true.

Comment: .. sesms to be the best (of the worst) solution because mixins don't really get rendered into resulting CSS.

Answer (score 2):

```
    %some-css {
      //CSS goes here.
    }

    .another-class {
      @extend %some-css;
    }
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes